# Need syntax help inserting the '.date()' within a '$doc->save()' function, which is sandwiched between a text filename and a file extension

Tags: php, xml, date, save

I am trying to sneak in the date by using the  `.date("Y-m-d-H-i")` format within my `$doc->save(filename.xml);`

the Obvious reason would be to create an archive function and NOT overwrite files continually.

I have tried various organizations with no luck

As an example:

`$doc->save('fileName'.date("Y-m-d-H-i")'.xml');`  But this crashes, I have tried various forms and placments of " \ " with no luck.

Anyone with ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `$doc->save('fileName'.date("Y-m-d-H-i").'.xml');` // note the extra dot

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes, he has missed a `.` in the code. Well spotted. Deserves a +15 rep Accepted Answer. +1

Comment: Many thanks to you!  That certainly did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the syntax provided by PeeHaa was the solution. I was missing a "."

$doc->save('fileName'.date("Y-m-d-H-i").'.xml');